# How to download codes from a specific branch in GIT

Tags: git, gitlab

Please assist me. I have git repository at git@gitlab.cube.go:harry/platform.git.
Under it are the following branches:

```
* dev
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/dev
  remotes/origin/dev
  remotes/origin/dev-24022021
  remotes/origin/dev-sc-management
  remotes/origin/feature/logging
```

What I want to do is to download the codes from remotes/origin/dev-sc-management to my local machine.
Work on it and later push it to my own branch, which I also want to know how to create. Can someone please let me know of the steps. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `git clone`-command downloads all branches from the repository by default.

If you want to update the remote branches, you can use `git fetch`.

If you want to update a local branch with the contents of a remote branch, you can use `git pull [<remote name>]`. This essentially runs a `fetch` and a `merge`.

You can see that you currently are on branch `dev` because there is a `*` right next to it.

In order to load another branch, you need to check it out:

```
git checkout dev-sc-management
```

This is actually a short form of

```
git checkout -b dev-sc-management remotes/origin/dev-sc-management
```

It creates a new branch named `dev-sc-management` from `remotes/origin/dev-sc-management`.

When you run it, `git branch -a` should look like:

```
  dev
* dev-sc-management
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/dev
  remotes/origin/dev
  remotes/origin/dev-24022021
  remotes/origin/dev-sc-management
  remotes/origin/feature/logging
```

After that, you can work on it, make commits and push it to the remote using:

```
git push origin dev-sc-management
```

If you want to don't write the `origin dev-sc-management` every time when pushing, you can push it using

```
git push -u origin dev-sc-management
```

once so that it assigns the remote `origin` to the branch `dev-sc-management` and it subsequent pushes can be done by just running

```
git push
```

Comment: Thanks, that was good, my question is this, does the code from dev-sc-management gets downloaded into my local when this step is executed:
git checkout -b dev-sc-management remotes/origin/dev-sc-management. Thank you.

Comment: It gets downloaded when you clone/fetch from the repository. Also, if I answered your your question, I would appreciate you accepting my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes. it is clear now.